# Clear webview content in API 19+

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to clear webview content above Api 19+ .So i tried this code

> webview.clearView();

but this method is deprecated and usable below Api 19. After i check android developer then see

> Use WebView.loadUrl("about:blank") to reliably reset the view state and release page resources (including any running JavaScript).

So anyone guide me where we use webview.loadUrl("about:blank) and what it means 
**including any running JavaScript**

Comment: this is my code:

Comment: _"where we use webview.loadUrl("about:blank)"_ The same place where you would've used `clearView`?  _"what it means including any running JavaScript"_ That any javascript that was running in your `WebView` before `loadUrl` will be stopped? Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Can you provide some codes, its not the clear what you actually want to achieve

Comment: i am doing in  button click.....observableWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                observableWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String url="https://www.facebook.com";
                observableWebView.loadUrl(url);

Comment: but when i doing webview.loadUrl("about:blank") then show a blank page before loading facebook page

Comment: _"but when i doing webview.loadUrl("about:blank") then show a blank page"_ Which is what the documentation for `clearView` says it will do: _"Clears this WebView so that onDraw() **will draw nothing but white background**"_.